# Object already defined but I'm not sure where

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fatal-error

I'm new to C++ and the error codes aren't really compelling to me.

I am trying to build a simple C++ OOP program as a homework assignment but which will gather then display information about book etc.

I am getting an error:

```
1>Book.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Author::getFullName(void)" (?getFullName@Author@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) already defined in Author.obj
1>Book.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Author::setFirstName(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?setFirstName@Author@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in Author.obj
1>Book.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Author::setLastName(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?setLastName@Author@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in Author.obj
1>Publisher.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Publisher::Publisher(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Publisher@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00@Z) already defined in Book.obj
1>Publisher.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Publisher::Publisher(void)" (??0Publisher@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Book.obj
1>Publisher.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Publisher::getPublisherInfo(void)" (?getPublisherInfo@Publisher@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) already defined in Book.obj
1>Publisher.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Publisher::setAddress(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?setAddress@Publisher@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in Book.obj
1>Publisher.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Publisher::setCity(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?setCity@Publisher@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in Book.obj
1>Publisher.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Publisher::setName(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?setName@Publisher@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in Book.obj
1>C:\Users\pc\Desktop\School\ITS 340\Labs\Lab 1\Lab 1\Debug\Lab 1.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Am I missing something here?

**Book.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Author.cpp"
#include "Publisher.cpp"

class Book
{
    public:
        Book();
        Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price);
        ~Book();
        void setTitle(string title);
        void setAuthorName(string first, string last);
        void setPublisher(string name, string address, string city);
        void setPrice(double price);
        string convertDoubleToString(double number);
        string getBookInfo();

    private:
        string title;
        double price;
        Author *pAuthor;
        Publisher *pPublisher;
};

Book::Book()
{
}

Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
    title = title;
    price = price;
}

Book::~Book()
{
}

void Book::setTitle(string  title)
{
}

void Book::setAuthorName(string first, string last)
{
}

void Book::setPublisher(string name, string address, string city)
{
}

void Book::setPrice(double price)
{
}

string Book::convertDoubleToString(double number)
{
    return 0;
}

string Book::getBookInfo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Publisher.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Publisher
{
    public: 
        Publisher();
        Publisher(string name, string address, string city);
        string getPublisherInfo();
        void setName(string name);
        void setAddress(string address);
        void setCity(string city);

    private:
        string name;
        string address;
        string city;
};

Publisher::Publisher()
{
}

Publisher::Publisher(string name, string address, string city)
{
    name = name;
    address = address;
    city = city;
}

string Publisher::getPublisherInfo()
{
    return "0";
}

void Publisher::setName(string name)
{
    name = name;
}

void Publisher::setAddress(string address)
{
    address = address;
}

void Publisher::setCity(string city)
{
    city = city;
}
```

Comment: it's probably not the source of the error, but in the constructors you should initialize the members like this:
`this->something = something;` or `Book(string title) : mTitle(title) {...}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should never include a `cpp` file in another `cpp` file or in a header. This almost inevitably leads to duplicate object definitions.

Put *declarations* into the header file, and *definitions* into the cpp files. Include headers in cpp files where you need to have access to methods of objects defined in other cpp files.

Take `Publisher.cpp` as an example: the top part up to and including the `};` line need to go into the `Publisher.h` file. Everything else has to remain in the `Publisher.cpp`. In addition, you need to add `#include Publisher.h` to the top of `Publisher.cpp`, along with other headers that you need to include.

You also need to remove `using namespace std;` from the header, and use `std::string` in your declarations. It is OK to put `using` in your `cpp` file, though.

Answer (score 4):

Use `#IFNDEF` to avoid duplicate object definitions if you are really in need to add some cpp to another cpp.

Like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef CPPADDED
#define CPPADDED

class Publisher
{...}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Dasblinkenlight said,

Your problem is that you did not use `ifndef` guard. You should use that to avoid this error. A quick search will give you the hint how to add headers.

Answer (score 1):

Create header file example: resource.h and put there prototypes of functions also class.
So it will look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Book
{
public:
    Book();
    Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price);
    ~Book();
    void setTitle(string title);
    void setAuthorName(string first, string last);
    void setPublisher(string name, string address, string city);
    void setPrice(double price);
    string convertDoubleToString(double number);
    string getBookInfo();

private:
    string title;
    double price;
    Author *pAuthor;
    Publisher *pPublisher;
};
class Publisher
{
public: 
    Publisher();
    Publisher(string name, string address, string city);
    string getPublisherInfo();
    void setName(string name);
    void setAddress(string address);
    void setCity(string city);

private:
    string name;
    string address;
    string city;
};
class Author{
    //... prototypes
};
```

Edit Book.cpp to this:

```
#include "resource.h"
Book::Book()
{
}

Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
title = title;
price = price;
}

Book::~Book()
{
}

void Book::setTitle(string  title)
{
}

void Book::setAuthorName(string first, string last)
{
}

void Book::setPublisher(string name, string address, string city)
{
}

void Book::setPrice(double price)
{
}

string Book::convertDoubleToString(double number)
{
    return 0;
}

string Book::getBookInfo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And Publisher.cpp to this:

```
#include "resource.h"
Publisher::Publisher()
{
}

Publisher::Publisher(string name, string address, string city)
{
    name = name;
    address = address;
    city = city;
}

string Publisher::getPublisherInfo()
{
    return "0";
}

void Publisher::setName(string name)
{
    name = name;
}

void Publisher::setAddress(string address)
{
    address = address;
}

void Publisher::setCity(string city)
{
    city = city;
}
```

And try to do same with Author.cpp,so you put function's prototypes (class) to "resource.h" and include "resource.h" to Author.cpp.